# Breadcrumb based on views, taxonomy and nodes, how to configure this?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

i'm developing my first Drupal project and i'm wondering how should alter the breadcrumbs and active menu item. part of my site setup is as follows:

- Virtual Exhibitions (which is a view, that lists all the taxonomy terms related to a certain taxonomy vocabulary, breadcrumb should be "home > Virtual exhibitions")

  - Themes (which is one of the taxonomy terms listed in the Virtual Exhibitions view, breadcrumb should be "home > Virtual exhibitions > Themes")

    - Theme1 (which is a node which has the taxonomy Themes configured, breadcrumb should be "home > Virtual exhibitions > Themes > Theme1")
    - Theme2
  - Persons

    - Person1
    - Person2

So the first page gives a list of exhibition categories (which are taxonomy terms). The second page is the exhibition category itselfs (the taxonomy term). And the last page is a node which has the taxonomy term configured.

Now because i'm using 3 different things i don't know how i should configure the breadcrumbs. Because the whole hierarchy should be in it. I tried different modules (Taxonomy breadcrumb, Menu trail, Taxonomy context) and all of them just do a small thing of what i need. Doesn't anyone have a good solution on how to handle this?

king regards,
Daan

Answer (score 0):

The module [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) sounds like it'll do what you need: the x.x-2.x branch will generate breadcrumbs based on Views and Taxonomy (among a variety of other things) using a series of tokens. I use it on sites I develop with the same use case as you describe.